# boost::locale::to_lower throw bad_cast exception

Tags: c++, boost, boost-locale

Boost 1.54 x64 on Win 7 64bits and VS2010. Compiling as "Release x64" and running the following code:

```
#include <boost/locale/conversion.hpp>
std::wstring y = L"NoNseNSE";
std::wstring w = boost::locale::to_lower(y);
```

throw `std::bad_cast` exception. Nothing changes even after adding (as suggested elsewhere):

```
std::locale mylocale("");
std::locale::global(mylocale);
```

or changing `to_lower(y)` to: `to_lower(y, mylocale)` or using `std::string` instead of `std::wstring` or setting LANG in the environment.

The goal is to convert to lowercase Italian UTF-8 words. I don't have found around problems like this, so I presume it is my machine specific problem or a boost library problem. BTW I have downloaded the precompiled boost library (boost_1_54_0-msvc-10.0-64.exe) from sourceforge. Any idea?
Thanks!
mario

Comment: if you use utf8, then `wstring` seems, by definition, out of the question

Answer (score 9):

This exception is thrown when your locale passed to `boost::locale::to_lower` (by default `std::locale()`, that is a copy of the global locale) does not have a `boost::locale::converter` facet installed. [See this for the related documentation.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/locale/doc/html/group__convert.html#ga4a3eb15f42f5cbae7bdd00c9e9cac222)

Use a `boost::locale::generator` to create the locale instead. (See also the examples linked to by the documentation, for example [this one](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/locale/doc/html/whello_8cpp-example.html#a7).)

Comment: Thanks, now it works. I was wrongly convinced `std::locale lx;` and `boost::locale::generator gen; std::locale lx=gen("");` were equivalent.