# Converting Turkish-I letter to lowercase using boost in CPP

Tags: c++, boost

Since a few days I was trying to get a C++ code that converts the Turkish `I` character to lowercase `ı` correctly on VS2022 on Windows.
As I understand, Turkish `I` has the same Unicode as regular Latin `I`, thus, I need to define the locale as Turkish before converting, I used the following code:

```
#include <clocale>
#include <cwctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::wstring input_str = L"I";
    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "tr_TR.UTF-8"); // This should impact std::towlower
    std::locale loc("tr_TR.UTF-8");
    std::wofstream output_file("lowercase_turkish.txt");
    output_file.imbue(loc);

    for (wchar_t& c : input_str) {
        c = std::towlower(c);
    }

    output_file << input_str << std::endl;
    output_file.close();
}
```

It worked fine on Linux, outputing `ı`, but didn't work correctly on Windows and it outputed `i` inplace of `ı`.
After some research I think it is a bug in Windows unicode/ascii mapping, so I went to an alternative solution, using an external library called `boost`, here is my code:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

using namespace boost::algorithm;

int main()
{
    std::string s = "I";
    std::locale::global(std::locale{ "Turkish" });
    to_lower(s);
    ofstream outfile("output.txt");
    outfile << s << endl;
    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

again, outputing `i` inplace of `ı`. also using `to_lower_copy` outputs the same.

Comment: `boost::algorithm::to_lower` is `void` and worls on the `std::string` you pass in by reference. You should also set the locale before doing any conversions.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I updated my code, is it right? as it still outputs `i`

Comment: Does setting the locale work? You don't check that it does.

Comment: Turkish dotless I has Unicode value of 0x131, so it does not fit in a normal char. In other words to solve this you have an encoding issue as well as a translation issue. You might have more luck with `std::wstring`

Comment: You may want to use boost::locale::gen, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751189/boostlocaleto-lower-throw-bad-cast-exception). Also bear in mind that boost locales may be backed by stdlib, winapi, or ICU. You want the ICU backend, see [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/locale/doc/html/using_localization_backends.html)